# VBA Comparison Operators Evaluating Incorrect with Case

Tags: vba, comparison-operators

I have a code block which is consistently evaluating incorrectly . I'm at a loss as to why this might be.

I've determined that it must be something to do with my 'Select Case' at the very least. If the order of operators is changed, e.g. `=, >, <` or `<, =, >` etc. the evaluation changes.

My expectation is that the evaluation would be `a = b` with the eventuality that `highest_header = 24` - While `24` is inevitably assigned to `highest_header`, my code does so using what I believe to be the wrong 'Case'.

I have simplified the code snippet slightly, but the result is the same - the comparison is being evaluated as `a = b = FALSE` and `a < b = TRUE`

```
Sub highest_header()
Dim highest_header_count As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

a = 24
b = 24

Debug.Print a '24
Debug.Print b '24
Debug.Print TypeName(a) 'Integer
Debug.Print TypeName(b) 'Integer

Select Case highest_header_count
    Case a = b
        highest_header_count = b
    Case a < b
        highest_header_count = b
    Case a > b
        highest_header_count = a
End Select

End Sub
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need IF Else statements instead of Select Case here.
Also in the Select Case you are using the wrong variable highest_header_count.

```
Sub highest_header()
Dim highest_header_count As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

a = 24
b = 24

Debug.Print a '24
Debug.Print b '24
Debug.Print TypeName(a) 'Integer
Debug.Print TypeName(b) 'Integer

If a = b Then
    highest_header_count = b
ElseIf a < b Then
    highest_header_count = b
ElseIf a > b Then
    highest_header_count = a
End If

End Sub
```

OR use your code like this...

```
Sub highest_header()
Dim highest_header_count As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

a = 24
b = 24

Debug.Print a '24
Debug.Print b '24
Debug.Print TypeName(a) 'Integer
Debug.Print TypeName(b) 'Integer

Select Case True
    Case a = b
        highest_header_count = b
    Case a < b
        highest_header_count = b
    Case a > b
        highest_header_count = a
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Ahhh that's where i was going wrong, major brain fart. `Select Case True` vs `Select Case ...no useful condition` Thank you very much!

Comment: @NHanson Don't worry, it happens with all of us. Glad you found it helpful.

Comment: @sktneer actualy you can use `Select Case a - b`, see my code below. Also, first 2 scenarios lead to the same result `highest_header_count = b`, so you can "merge" these 2 cases

Comment: @ShaiRado Using case a-b is irrelevant here as you will have to evaluate all other cases based on this single case. Using True makes the code simple, easy to read and easy to understand. :)

Comment: @sktneer tomato to-ma-to , at least merge both 2 first scenarios, or is it also easier to read this way ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Well that's not a point to argue. It's just matter of your choice. :)

Comment: Thanks for the input all. I've actually settled on a slightly less verbose solution that still satisfies my use case by using `iif()`. `a = 24, b = 24, highest_header = iif(a < b, b, a)`

Answer (score 3):

Your Select Case is comparing an integer with a value of 0 to a Boolean.

`a = b` is True which is -1,
`a < b` is False which is 0,
`a > b` is False which is 0.

So that is why you are getting a hit on `a < b`.

Comment: highest_header_count is an integer, Case tests for **its** value.   When you put the Cases below, you actually test against Boolean values that are casted to ints.

Answer (score 3):

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HighestHeader()
    Dim highest_header_count As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long

    a = 24
    b = 24

    Debug.Print a '24
    Debug.Print b '24
    Debug.Print TypeName(a) 'Long
    Debug.Print TypeName(b) 'Long

    Select Case a
        Case Is = b
            highest_header_count = b
        Case Is < b
            highest_header_count = b
        Case Is > b
            highest_header_count = a
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

You are comparing `highest_header_count` against the 3 comparisons (`a = b`, etc)

Answer (score 1):

**Or**, you can use `Select Case`, just "trick" it a little.

You can use `Select Case a - b` , and then check `Case 0`, `Case Is < 0` and `Case Is > 0`, see my code below:

```
Sub highest_header()

Dim highest_header_count As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

a = 24
b = 24

Debug.Print a '24
Debug.Print b '24
Debug.Print TypeName(a) 'Integer
Debug.Print TypeName(b) 'Integer

Select Case a - b
    Case 0
        highest_header_count = b
    Case Is < 0
        highest_header_count = b
    Case Is > 0
        highest_header_count = a
End Select

End Sub
```

You can make the `Select Case` even shorter:

```
Select Case a - b
    Case 0, Is < 0 ' <-- both scenarios lead to the same result
        highest_header_count = b      
    Case Is > 0
        highest_header_count = a
End Select
```